# c++ operator overloading how to implement the pattern like the ctor of Mat_<type> in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, operator-overloading

In opencv, I can construct an object of Mat like this:

```
Mat mat = (Mat_<int>(2, 3) << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

So it's convenient to initialize an instance of `Mat_<type>`,and if I have a custom simplified matrix class `Mat2D`,in which i will use this pattern, but how to do?
**Update:** I tried to use variable length parameter list, but `error C2829: 'operator <<' cannot have a variable parameter list`.

Comment: You should overload `<<` and `,` operators.

Comment: @xaizek Overload operator `,`, now that's bold advice.

Comment: @Gorpik, yeah I know that overloading of operator `,` is a "VERY BAD THING", just forgot to write that in the comment. But now it should be clear for OP from your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WARNING: DO NOT DO THIS. YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED.

You can achieve this using operator overloading, but it is a very bad idea, as I'll explain later.

I'll assume class `Mat` has a constructor that takes a `Mat_<int>`.

I'll assume class template `Mat_<T>` has a method, `Insert()`, that knows how to insert a single element into a matrix. I'll let you work this out, but it'll need a way to know where to insert it.

Using this method it is easy to overload `operator<<`:

```
template<typename T>
Mat_<T>& operator<<(Mat_<T>& mat, const T& el)
{
  mat.Insert(el);
  return mat;
}
```

And we can overload `operator,` to call this overloaded `operator<<`:

```
template<typename T>
Mat_<T>& operator,(Mat_<T>& mat, const T& el)
{
  return mat << el;
}
```

Everything works fine and you can use your syntax. Now I will explain why this is a bad idea.

Overloading `operator<<` this way is perfectly sensible. This is the insertion operator and our overload inserts an element into the matrix. This is what anybody would expect; so far, so good.

But overloading `operator,` is not. The meaning of this operator is "evaluate two expressions, then return the last one"; this is clearly not what our overloaded operator does. Unwary users will try to use operator `,` in the standard way (for instance, in a `for` loop) and will not understand why their code does not work. You should never overload an operator to do a non-standard operation unless you want to be hated by whoever uses your code; probably yourself sometime later.

In fact, while the standard allows overloading `operator,`, this is something you should probably never do, because it is impossible to write code that does the standard operation. You can consider this a mistake in the standard that is kept for backward compatibility.

And, in case you were considering overloading `operator,` to take two `int` and somehow bundle them together, not only the drawbacks are even more serious: it is illegal to overload an operator when all operands are built-in types.

So, in summary: you can do it, but it is a bad idea and will cause bugs in unexpected places of your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of builder pattern with fluent interface using the inserter and comma operators as simple DSL. I do not see dangers of any kind (if done properly), since your DSL defines a very special context in which these operators apply. Have a look at boost::assign, if you are looking for inspiration. Anyway, I´d use verbal DSL elements instead of operators but this is just a matter of my personal preference...